# How to set commit message template in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, commit, mylyn, commit-message

Reading this article

> https://medium.freecodecamp.org/level-you-up-to-awesome-commit-messages-a85558cb90e8

I wanted to set my commit message template to show few comments to remind me of writing good commit messages.

I see many answers on how to set commit messages if I commit through console, but neither one is shown for commit messages in **Eclipse**.

I do not need tasks automatically added or nothing specific except few comments like this one:

```
> # [Add/Fix/Remove/Update/Refactor/Document] [summary]


# Why is it necessary? (Bug fix, feature, improvements?)
-
# How does the change address the issue? 
-
# What side effects does this change have?
-
# Include a link to the ticket, if any.
```

I tried setting .gitconfig file and Eclipse -> Preference -> Mylyn -> Team with mentioned comments, but commit message is not automatically added.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there were **Mylyn settings** in `Eclipse -> Preference -> Mylyn -> Team` so I assumed everything is installed properly.

After **reinstalling** Mylyn and installing all of it's **connectors**, it works fine.

--- EDIT ---

> I will leave this answer here if there will be someone with similar
>   problem, but if some of more experienced colleagues consider it not
>   necessary, just leave the comment and I will delete it.

Comment: Same issue here. Which connectors did you install? Seems that eclipse ignores commit.template git config

Comment: Seems to be a missing feature: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535844 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446355

Comment: @Mahatma_Fatal_Error I just checked this and I can confirm it does not work as expected anymore  (haven't used Eclipse for a while).